# What is Significance of _v(l) in the macro?

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to understand the following macro from the following [URL](https://docs.fd.io/vpp/17.10/db/d65/vec_8h.html):

```
do {                                                                    \
  word _v(l) = vec_len (V);                                             \
  V = _vec_resize ((V), 1, (_v(l) + 1) * sizeof ((V)[0]), (H), (A));    \
  (V)[_v(l)] = (E);                                                     \
} while (0)
```

what is the significance of _v(l)? Is it just a variable or something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_v` macro is defined in vec.h at [line 207](https://docs.fd.io/vpp/17.10/db/d65/vec_8h_source.html#l00206):

```
 #define _v(var) _vec_##var
```

This prepends `_vec_` before `var`. You can observe this by asking your favorite compiler to print the output of the preprocessor stage (`-E` flag for clang/gcc and `/E` for msvc).

```
#define _v(var) _vec_##var
word _v(l) = vec_len (V);
```

Is expanded into:

```
word _vec_l = vec_len (V);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a variable whose name is generated. The name probably includes the current line number to make it unique. Therefore using this macro twice in a line may or may not work.

To see what the macro expands to, run `gcc -E` to only preprocess the code but not compile it. Do a bit of research about this `-E` computer option, it is helpful in many similar cases as well.